# Change Truthy/Falsey value of Javascript Object

Tags: javascript

Basically can I do the following...

```
var obj = {}:
obj.falsey = true;
if(obj){
   //code not executed
}else{
   //code executed
}
```

I could take advantage of the fact `!`,`+`,`~`...
Call `valueOf/toString` and do the following, but I would like to avoid that.

```
var obj = {valueOf:function(){return 0}}:
obj.falsey = true;
if(!!obj){
   //code not executed
}else{
   //code executed
}
```

Why would I want to do this?  Because I'm curious :D

Comment: um, *duh* ...you have to do: `epicif(obj)`, then it'll work. :)

Comment: `!!obj` neither calls `obj.valueOf()` nor `obj.toString()`.

Comment: @Robert it used to work they may have adopted a new standard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can borrow a false `Number`,`Boolean`.... from an iframe and extend its prototype.

Basically the following doesn't work because Numbers are a primitive value.

```
var x = 0;
x.test = 'yo';
console.log(x.test);
```

This does, but obviously this pollutes the Number.prototype, so you should really borrow a different `Number` object from another iframe.

```
var x = 0;
Number.prototype.test = 'yo';
console.log(x.test);
```

Ultimately, just not a very good idea.

Comment: There are no falsy `Number`s or `Boolean`s. Also I don't see how borrowing a different object would make any difference at all.

Comment: @Robert I don't understand your question.  You can extend Number.prototype but can't add custom properties to object.  You theoretically could borrow a Number from an iframe I could post an example but it probably wouldn't be worth it doing such would be nasty and frankly really weird.

Comment: I mean, you can easily add custom properties to `Number` objects, like `x = new Number(0); x.test = 'yo';`. On the other hand extending `Number.prototype` of a different iframe wouldn't influence number primitives of the current frame at all.

Comment: @Robert you would have to do `x = NumberNewiframe(0)`  try to retrieve x.test it wouldn't work in your example.

Comment: `x = NumberNewiframe(0)` returns just a plain number primitive. There's no connection to the `NumberNewiframe.prototype` attached, so `alert(x.test)` would alert `undefined` since it create a temporary object from the unmodified `Number` constructor of the current context, which doesn't have a `test` property. But using the `new` keyword `x = new Number(0)` actually creates a persistent object you can modify, so `x.test = 'yo'; alert(x.test)` alerts `yo`.

Comment: @Robert I think I see what you mean like the following https://jsfiddle.net/resuqdyy/2/ and borrowing Number from an iframe works https://jsfiddle.net/resuqdyy/1/

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't. You have to implement some custom logic.

Answer (score -1):

You can use loose equal to compare it to a boolean. People do that all the time, and finally it serves some purpose.

```
var obj = {valueOf: function() {return !this.falsey;}};
obj.falsey = true;
if (obj == true) {
   //code not executed
} else if (obj == false) {
   //code executed
}
```